# Where does a pkg installer install things?

Tags: macos, install

I created a *.pkg installer for a command line tool following this guide: [Packaging a daemon for OS X](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2013-autoconf-osx-packaging.html).

After running the installer, and selecting "Install for all users", I can't find where my installed files are.

The installer says the setup will take 57.9MB and the copying section takes quite some seconds, so I assume files are actually being copied and there is not an issue with my installer.

Where did those files go? A `find /` didn't reveal anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can check it from Terminal. Navigate to the folder where You have Your `pkg` file. Enter this:

```
mkdir Foo
cd Foo
xar -xf ../NAME_OF_YOUR.pkg
lsbom Bom
```

This will list files/paths which are included in this `pkg`.

Comment: What is `Bom` supposed to be?

    $ lsbom Bom
    can't open Bom: No such file or directory
    **** Can't open Bom.

Comment: Is is a flat package? (it's not if You can `cd` into Your `.pkg`)

Comment: I can't cd to the pkg. `file` says: xar archive - version 1.

Comment: Can You list the contents of `Foo` dir after extracting Your `pkg` (`ls -la`)?

Comment: I can. I see Distribution, Resources and my cli.pkg.

Comment: Can you check what You get after `pkgutil --expand NAME_OF_YOUR.pkg DEST_DIR`? This should unpack Your `pkg` file to `DEST_DIR`.

Comment: I get the exact same results as above: Distribution, Resources and my cli.pkg.

Comment: What about `pkgutil list`? I can't remember if that works.

Comment: `--list` doesn't seems to exists. I tried `--files` and `--lsbom` but I get `No receipt for 'resin-cli-setup.pkg' found at '/'.` for both of them.

Comment: Turns out it was extracted directly to `/`. I specified a `customLocation` property in `choices` to fix it.